# Read specific floating point values from lines of the command output

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, grep

Running terminal command prints output in following form:

> *some irrelevant text*
>   *more irrelevant text*
>   VALUE A = 3.14
>   VALUE B = 2.71
>   *also irrelevant text*

I need shell command (or awk) that would get the floating point values which correspond to VALUE A (3.14) and VALUE B (2.71) and assign them to shell variables based on the preceding string. It is important to use the string as identification and extract those particular lines in such format.

Would be great to avoid, but it is possible to temporarily store command output in a text file for processing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the input that you provided, this will do what you asked for:

```
$ declare $(mycommand | sed -n 's/^\([^=]*\) = /\1=/p' | tr ' ' '_')
$ echo $VALUE_A
3.14
$ echo $VALUE_B
2.71
```

The `sed` script will pick out any line handed to it from `mycommand` (your data generator) containing an `=` surrounded by a single space on either side, remove these spaces and pass its output to `tr` which will replace spaces with underscores.  The `declare` carries out the assignment in the current shell, creating new environment variables.

In steps (with your sample data in `input`):

```
$ cat input
some irrelevant text
more irrelevant text
VALUE A = 3.14
VALUE B = 2.71
also irrelevant text

$ cat input | sed -n 's/^\([^=]*\) = /\1=/p'
VALUE A=3.14
VALUE B=2.71

$ cat input | sed -n 's/^\([^=]*\) = /\1=/p' | tr ' ' '_'
VALUE_A=3.14
VALUE_B=2.71
```

... and `declare` carries these assignments out.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as "irrelevant text". If your "irrelevant text" contains an `=` sign, for example, then some solutions will break. If it's multi-line, other solutions will break, etc, etc. You have to tell us more about that "irrelevant text" and use a concrete example in your sample input/output if you want to get a robust solution.

Having said that, one possible solution depending on your "irrelevant text" requirements is:

```
$ declare $( cat file | awk -F' *= *' -v OFS='=' 'NF>1{gsub(/ /,"_",$1); print}' )

$ echo "$VALUE_A"
3.14
$ echo "$VALUE_B"
2.71
```

Another:

```
$ declare $( cat file | awk -F' *= *' -v OFS='=' 'NR>2 && NR<5{gsub(/ /,"_",$1); print}' )
```

Replace `cat file` with whatever command you are executing to produce the output you show as sample input in your question.

With this and any other solution, since you haven't told us what "irrelevant text" can/can't contain, you may find that text isn't as irrelevant as you'd like it do be since it may fit a pattern we're assuming only exists in the "relevant" lines.

Answer (score 0):

Run:

```
while read -r a b c d; do [ "$a" = VALUE ] && [ "$c" = = ] && declare "VALUE_$b=$d"; done < <(command)
```

Or, if you prefer commands spread over several lines:

```
while read -r a b c d
do
  [ "$a" = VALUE ] && [ "$c" = = ] && declare "VALUE_$b=$d"
done < <(command)
```

This requires bash.

#### How it works

- `while read -r a b c d; do`

  This starts a loop and reads from standard input, divides it up into words and assigns the variables `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`.
- `[ "$a" = VALUE ] && [ "$c" = = ] && declare "VALUE_$b=$d"`

  If `a` is VALUE and `c` is an equal sign, then create a shell variable with name `VALUE_$b` and value `$d`.
- `done`

  This marks the end of the loop.
- `< <(command)`

  This provides input to the loop from the output of the `command`.

  The first `<` indicates that input to the loop should be redirected.  The construct `<(...)` provides the input, via *process substitution*, from the output of `command`.